# ORA-31011 on XMLTYPE column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xmltype, ora-31011

I'm using Oracle version - 11.2.0.4

I've reproduced the problem I'm facing in a more simplified manner below. 
I've 2 tables with XMLTYPE column. 
Table 1 (base_table in my example below) has storage model for XMLTYPE as BINARY XML. 
Table 2 (my_tab) has storage model for XMLTYPE as CLOB.

With the XML in base_table I'm extracting the value of an attribute based on certain condition. This attribute in turn is a name of a node in xml contained in my_tab and I want to extract that node's value from my_tab. 
Please note that I do not have the liberty to change this logic at the moment.

Code was working fine till the storage model for XMLTYPE column was CLOB in both tables. Recently base_table was recreated (drop and create), so it's storage model got modified as BINARY XML as I understand that's the default storage model in version 11.2.0.4

Here is create table stmt and sample data -

```
create table base_table(xml xmltype);
create table my_tab(xml xmltype)
xmltype column "XML" store as clob;

insert into base_table(xml)
values (xmltype('<ROOT>
  <ELEMENT NAME="NODEA">
    <NODE1>A-Node1</NODE1>
    <NODE2>A-Node2</NODE2>
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT NAME="NODEB">
    <NODE1>B-Node1</NODE1>
    <NODE2>B-Node2</NODE2>
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT NAME="NODEC">
    <NODE1>C-Node1</NODE1>
    <NODE2>C-Node2</NODE2>
  </ELEMENT>
</ROOT>')
);

insert into my_tab(xml)
values (xmltype('<TEST_XML>
  <SOME_NODE>
    <XYZ>
      <NODEB>My area of concern</NODEB>
      <OTHER_NODE> Something irrelevant </OTHER_NODE>
    </XYZ>
  </SOME_NODE>
  <SOME_OTHER_NODE>
    <ABC> Some value for this node </ABC>
  </SOME_OTHER_NODE>
</TEST_XML>')
);
```

Below query fails:

```
select extract(t.xml, sd.tag_name).getstringval()
from (select '//' || extract(value(d), '//@NAME').getstringval() || '/text()' as tag_name
        from base_table b,
             table(xmlsequence(extract(b.xml, '//ROOT/ELEMENT'))) d
       where extract(value(d), '//NODE2/text()').getstringval() = 'B-Node2') sd,
my_tab t;

ORA-31011: XML parsing failed 
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing 
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '///text()'
```

However, this query works fine and is able to extract the value of node I'm interested in. It can be seen that tag_name is fetched as required, but when it is used within "extract", it's value is somehow lost.

```
select sd.tag_name, extract(t.xml, '//NodeB/text()').getstringval()
from (select '//' || extract(value(d), '//@NAME').getstringval() || '/text()' as tag_name
        from base_table b,
             table(xmlsequence(extract(b.xml, '//ROOT/ELEMENT'))) d
       where extract(value(d), '//NODE2/text()').getstringval() = 'B-Node2') sd,
my_tab t;
```

---

If I change XMLTYPE storage model of base_table back to CLOB, the erroneous query works fine again.

I would like to understand what's going wrong with storage model as BINARY XML.

I modified query as below, which is working fine. i.e. convert to clob and back to XMLTYPE:

```
select extract(t.xml, sd.tag_name).getstringval() 
from (select '//' || extract(value(d), '//@NAME').getstringval() || '/text()' as tag_name 
 from base_table b, 
 table(xmlsequence(extract(XMLTYPE(b.xml.getclobval()), '//ROOT/ELEMENT'))) d 
 where extract(value(d), '//NODE2/text()').getstringval() = 'B-Node2') sd, 
my_tab t;
```

Thanks,
Kailash